# Jquery datatables. Array of rows of visible columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I'm trying to extract an array of rows from my datatable. My problem is that I have some fields of the json that populates the table that I don't show in the table. When I use

```
$('#myTable').DataTable().rows().data().toArray()
```

I get those fields that I don't need.

¿How can I get that array of the shown fields or columns?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [selector-modifier](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier).

```
$('#myTable').DataTable().rows({search:'applied'}).data().toArray();
```

**-------------------------------------**

**EDIT**

A possible way to accomplish what you are asking for is to check first what columns are visible. Then, process each result row and get only the fields you want.

```
var columns = $('#myTable').DataTable().columns().visible();
var rows = $('#myTable').DataTable().rows().data().toArray();
var result = []; // this array will contain only the visible fields of each row
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; ++j)
        if (columns[j]) // is visible
            row.push(rows[i][j]);
    result.push(row);
}
```

Comment: Hi Dacklf, I get the same result using a selector-modifier. The problem is that in order to populate the datatable I use a json with more fields that I use in the table. And using data() i get those fields that I don't need this time. Thanks for your time

Comment: oh sorry, I missunderstood what you were asking for. Check the edit.

Comment: This has been my solution:

Comment: This has been my solution:    var data = [];
        $('#myTable').DataTable().rows().every(function (rowIdx) {
            datat.push($.extend({}, this.cells(rowIdx, ':visible').data().toArray()));
        });